# Java project does not run after Maven-enabling it

Tags: java, maven, debugging, build

I could build (run/debug) my Java project on Netbeans before I made it *maven-enabled* to better handle the dependancies. Now the project builds successfully, but I can't run/debug it.

When I click on debug/run buttons, in the output window I see a message that the project is successfully built, but the application does not start.

When I double-click on the created jar file, I get this message: **The Java JAR file "myProject-SNAPSHOT.jar" could not be launched. Check the Console for possible error messages.** 
But I don't see any error message on the console.

**Update 1**
This is how my `pom.xml` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>MyGroupID</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyProjectName</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcommon</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.23</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

**Update 2**
Here is the output of `mvn -X clean package`:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building GeMSE 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ GeMSE ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/user/NetBeansProjects/GeMSE_Maven_Enabled/GeMSE/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ GeMSE ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/user/NetBeansProjects/GeMSE_Maven_Enabled/GeMSE/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ GeMSE ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 73 source files to /Users/user/NetBeansProjects/GeMSE_Maven_Enabled/GeMSE/target/classes
[WARNING] /Users/user/NetBeansProjects/GeMSE_Maven_Enabled/GeMSE/src/main/java/GeMSE/Importers/GTFParser.java: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[WARNING] /Users/user/NetBeansProjects/GeMSE_Maven_Enabled/GeMSE/src/main/java/GeMSE/Importers/GTFParser.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ GeMSE ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/user/NetBeansProjects/GeMSE_Maven_Enabled/GeMSE/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ GeMSE ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ GeMSE ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ GeMSE ---
[INFO] Building jar: /Users/user/NetBeansProjects/GeMSE_Maven_Enabled/GeMSE/target/GeMSE-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.838 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-03-06T15:10:25-08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/312M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What is the output of mvn -X clean package?

Comment: @asettouf see Update 2.

Comment: I am pretty sure there is more than just Build success in the output!

Comment: @asettouf yes, there is a very long list listing all my classes (1K+) with `[DEBUG] adding entry XYZ' and many other with `[DEBUG]` and `[INFO]` prefixes. If you let me know what you're looking for, I'll give provide that specific info

Comment: I don't think it is that long, anyway SO will handle the formatting pretty well when you copy and paste it. Since there is no error, I would need more informations to be able to be looking for something

Comment: it's really big, and adding SO I got this error message: `Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 127487.`

Comment: Ok then just add the maven output of mvn clean package (without the "X" switch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens it that you jar cannot be executed because:

- either the manifest entry which specifies the main class is not here,
- and/or required dependencies are not bundled with the JAR file.

You have to build your jar bundled with the dependencies. Define in your pom.xml:

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
      <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
     <execution>
       <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
       <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
       <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
       </goals>
     </execution>
   </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

Then you can create the JAR file by calling in a terminal:

> mvn clean compile assembly:single

It's common to tie the assembly task to the package phase, to ensure building the jar with dependencies when executing *mvn package*.

Comment: I just updated my question, with how my `pom.xml` looks now. This seems way different from what you explained !